# Determining valueBinding for Ember.TextField at runtime

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to create a generic editor page in an Ember.js app.

I need to create a few TextFields to bind to attributes on a model, but I will only know at runtime what fields this model has. My controller has an field called metadata, which describes the fields for this generic editor form. I want to iterate over the contents of this metadata and build up the form directly. Essentially I'm trying to do this:

```
{{#each row in metadata.rows}}
  {{#each element in row.elements}}
    {{element.fieldName}}: {{view Ember.TextField valueBindinding=model.get(fieldName)  }}<br>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

This of course doesn't work as the TextField is expecting a reference to a model attribute that it can bind to.

I have created a fiddle here which illustrates the problem and my attempt to solve it:  http://jsfiddle.net/ianpetzer/HAecb/

Thanks for any help

Comment: you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/HAecb/3/

Comment: Kind of.... Except I'd like the value of the TextField bound to the variable so that if I modify it, the changes show up automatically in the manually bound textField and display area.. Thanks for your help so far.